# Ionic ActionSheetController and ion-range

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to have 'ion-range' in the ActionSheet or AlertController of the ionic2 web app. Can anyone help who has done this before?

I am looking for an implementation similar to the pop-up on iOS that is brought up by dragging a finger from off the bottom of the screen onto the screen (contains slider to adjust brightness, bluetooth, etc.). I want to achieve the same functionality. So far I've tried using Ionic 2's [ActionSheet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.9/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheet/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show code you've written to try and solve this problem.

Comment: Hello @Nick, I'm not yet started the code now I'm in the phase where I'm deciding what all are possible ways we can acchive and what we can't. For you simplicity you can find the code for ActionSheet here [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#action-sheets) Here the issue is that it accepts Button as property in the object which we are using to create the ActionSheet. Here I need ion-range instead of the Button.